# Why doesn't my discord.py welcome message work?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code I used before. But it suddenly stopped working. I can't figure out how to fix this.

````py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome", description=f"Hi {member.mention} welcome to {guild.name}")
    embed.set_footer(text="UnhelpfulBOT© | Made by Kezz#4058")
    await bot.get_channel(channel_id).send(content=None, embed=embed)```
````

Comment: What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I want it to send messages but it doesnt send anything. I dont get an error either. I already tried allowing intends but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Try putting a print statement in that function, just to make sure it's being executed when a new member joins.

Comment: I put the print at the first possible line but no response in terminal. so it doesn't execute i think

Answer (score 0):

First let's get the guild not via some magic variables but through the member who joined ([Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild))

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome", description=f"Hi {member.mention} welcome to {guild.name}")
    embed.set_footer(text="UnhelpfulBOT© | Made by Kezz#4058")
```

Now we need to send the message in the channel the member joined.
The general channel where members join is the `guild.system_channel` ([Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel)). If this channel is not set, we do not send a message.

```py
system_channel = guild.system_channel

if system_channel is None:
    print('No system channel found')
else:
    await.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: @kezz please specify what it is not working with my solution. You will not get any useful answers if you do not specify the problems you are having.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a few errors, and I think this is more of what your code should look like. As for you not receiving any error message, that is a very odd thing that I'm not sure why is happening.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = await bot.get_guild(guild_id)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Welcome",
        description = f"Hi {member.mention} welcome to {guild.name}"
)

embed.set_footer(text = "UnhelpfulBOT© | Made by Kezz#4058")

channel = await bot.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: Please specify what is now working. Is there an error message? Did the function not get called?